# how to change condition in if template tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I am trying to use some value that I get from clicking a button to be loaded in the if statement in my HTML template. but cannot do so.maybe I am doing everything wrong.

I have used var tag and placed my variable inside it but it didn't work when I tried to edit it through javascript code

```
{% for publication in page.get_children.specific %}
{% if publication.pub_type ==  <var id="varpubtype">pubtype</var> %}
{% if publication.pub_year == <var id="varpubyear">pubyear</var> %}
    <tr>

         <td>{{ publication.Authors }}</td>
         <td>{{ publication.name }}</td
         <td>{{ publication.pub_year }}</td>
         <td>{{ publication.pub_journal }}</td>
         <td>{{ publication.vol_issue }}</td>
         <td>{{ publication.pages }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

here is my script

```
 function toggletable( var pubtypevar)
  {
       document.getElementById("varpubtype").innerHTML = pubtypevar;
  }

  function toggleyear( var pubyearvar){
       document.getElementById('varpubyear').innerHTML = pubyearvar;
  }
```

when i used var and span tags it showed template error. That
Could not parse the remainder: '

Comment: Django templates are rendered at *server* side, not at client side, so indeed, that makes not much sense.

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't seem like that, you have to do the condition on the server not on the client, and the page reload when you click that button,

and then you use condition from server then you implementation on the client

Comment: so do i have to make 5 more tables with different conditions ?? and then use css display :none, or it can be done in a short manner??  I am new to it and still exploring

Comment: yes you make 5 more tables or condition corresponding on result from your server, 

no use css, only use conditions, if the condition is true then the element will be displayed, if not then the element will not display